# People tell me this is scam. Is it?

Tags: fraud

Since a couple of weeks, a contact from LinkedIn is helping me on the cryptocurrency market. Very successful, but when I want to pick up my money now, I have to pay a mining fee. The mining fee is big and needs to be paid with fresh money, so my wallet can not be used. Scam or is this normal?